# Enrty to addEventListener

Tags: javascript, web

The add Event Listener Doesn't call the Play function and i don't understand why?

```
var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
var title = document.querySelector('#title');
var count = 0, rand = 0 , sum =0;
var one = document.getElementById('one');
btn.addEventListener('click',play);


function play()
{
count = 8200;
this.rand = Math.floor(Math.random() *7)+1;
this.sum +=rand;
one.textContent = sum;
if(sum >= 100)
    {
        title.textContent = 'You won!'
    }
}
```

I tried to debug id on Firefox debugger and it's show that it jump 
directly to the end of the code.
why the play method doesn't execute?

Comment: What if you add a `console.log('inside play');` as first line of the function? Either way, please provide a [mcve]. Otherwise we cannot really help you.

Comment: Maybe a syntax error? `this. rand = Math.floor(Math.random() *7)+1;` with a space after `this.`

Comment: So the console print 'inside play' but on the debugger the rand,sum,count doesn't change

Comment: @LudovitMydla that's not a syntax error but it is a logic error. `btn.rand` does not exist.

Comment: @LudovitMydla no it doesn't help

Comment: as @Patrick Roberts said, that was not the case. Just my quick guess

Comment: How can i step into the play function with Firefox debugger? it's only let me step into if i write play() , but not from the Btn event line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `this`. `this` inside the `play()` will be `btn` element on which event is triggered.

> If attaching a handler function to an element using `addEventListener()`, the value of **`this` inside the handler is a reference to the element**

See [**The value of `this` within the handler**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler)

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
var title = document.querySelector('#title');
var count = 0, rand = 0 , sum =0;
var one = document.getElementById('one');
btn.addEventListener('click',play);


function play()
{
  count = 8200;
  rand = Math.floor(Math.random() *7)+1;
  sum +=rand;
  one.textContent = sum;
  if(sum >= 100)
  {
     title.textContent = 'You won!'
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">click</button>
<div id="title">Title</div>
<div id="one"></div>
```